# Random phone number xxx or yyy + operator number mm or nn + a random 6 or 7 digit number in php

Tags: php

I need the code to generate a random phone number and if it chooses the 331 prefix then it has to have the 2x operator numbers, if it chooses the 333 then it has to contain the 5x operator numbers, and at last the random number, but if it's 381 then it's 7 digit number and if it is 389 it's a 6 digit number I have done this, but at the end it doesn't print out anything.

```
<?php
        //an array containing the prefixes
        $string_preprefix = array('a' => '331', 'b' => '333',);
        shuffle($string_preprefix);
        reset($string_preprefix);

        an array containing the operator numbers for the 389 prefix
        $string_prefix = array('20', '22', '23', '24', '26', '28', '29',);
        shuffle($string_prefix);
        reset($string_prefix);

        //an array containing the operator numbers for the 381 prefix
        $string_prefix = array('53', '54', '55', );
        shuffle($string_prefix);
        reset($string_prefix);

        //a function that generates random number
        function generateRandomNumber($length = 6) {
            $number = '1234567890';
            $numberLength = strlen($number);
            $randomNumber = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                $randomNumber .= $number[rand(0, $numberLength - 1)];
            }
            return $randomNumber;
        }

        //the if/elseif method doesn't print anything
        if ($string_preprefix == ['a']):
            echo $string_preprefix . $string_prefix . generateRandomNumber(6);
        elseif($string_preprefix == ['b']):
            echo $string_preprefix . $string_prefix . generateRandomNumber(7);
        endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` there are a couple of problems, unless there was a copy paste error.

Comment: I don't think the `shuffle()` and `reset()` functions do what you want. The way you have it now, `$string_preprefix` will never equal `['a']` or `['b']` like you're checking for. You might want to assign `$string_preprefix` using `array_rand()`. See the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues. First, if you reset the arrays *before* you echo them you will get the same result each time.

Next, you need to test the [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) of the element in the first position of the array against a string, like `'a'`, not `['a']` as the second example will never match unless your key has the brackets in it.

Lastly, you have to return the element in the first position of any subsequent array which has been shuffled. You have two arrays with the same name , `$string_prefix` - the second overwrites the first. You will need additional logic to make the decision there:

```
//an array containing the prefixes
$string_preprefix = array('a' => '331', 'b' => '333',);
shuffle($string_preprefix);
//reset($string_preprefix);

if('389' == $string_preprefix[0]) { // this value is not in the original array
    //an array containing the operator numbers for the 389 prefix
    $string_prefix = array('20', '22', '23', '24', '26', '28', '29',);
    shuffle($string_prefix);
    //reset($string_prefix);
} elseif ('381' == $string_preprefix[0]) { // this value is not in the original array
    //an array containing the operator numbers for the 381 prefix
    $string_prefix = array('53', '54', '55', );
    shuffle($string_prefix);
    //reset($string_prefix);
} else {
    $string_prefix = '0000';
}

//a function that generates random number
function generateRandomNumber($length = 6) {
    $number = '1234567890';
    $numberLength = strlen($number);
    $randomNumber = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomNumber .= $number[rand(0, $numberLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomNumber;
}

//the if/elseif method doesn't print anything
if (key($string_preprefix) == 'a'):
    echo $string_preprefix[0] . $string_prefix[0] . generateRandomNumber(6);
elseif(key($string_preprefix) == 'b'):
    echo $string_preprefix[0] . $string_prefix[0] . generateRandomNumber(7);
endif;
```

In addition, I agree with @IanDrake's comment - `shuffle()` likely doesn't do what you want. You'll want to perform a randomization of the array.